# vuexfire firestore orderBy descending is not working, works in acending

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuefire, vuexfire

This code works in default ascending but as soon as I feed desc in orderby, it returns empty.

```
return bindFirestoreRef(
        'codesBatch',
        codeCollection
          .orderBy('createdOn', 'desc')
          .limit(payload.limit || 3)
          .startAfter(state.loadMoreLastCode || null),
```

Comment: What do you mean by "orderBy descending is not working". What exactly doesn't work? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

`.orderBy()` 'desc' doesn't work with `.startAfter()` null.

The first call has to be without `.startAfter()` and for later, the above code will work.